# Problems matching div via xpath locators in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use regex to match an id containing an unpredictable number in the middle of an otherwise predictable string, an example:

```
<div id="type-84289-model" class="vehicle">
```

I've tried various things, but it seems like the most obvious that should work is:

```
By.xpath("//div[matches(@id, 'type-.+-model')]"));
```

However that doesn't find the element.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is it XPath 2? I think that XPath 1 doesn't support regular expressions.

Comment: In case @curiosu is right you may try `[starts-with(@id, 'type-') and ends-with(@id, '-model')]`.

Comment: I believe it supports Xpath 2.  From what I understand of Selenium it boils down to whatever the browser you're testing supports and I've been using Firefox 31.0.  However, I did try using 'starts-with' and 'ends-with' as @Ciapan suggest, but no luck...  I'm getting an InvalidSelectorException exception.

Comment: I'm surprised at the implication that Firefox supports XPath 2.0. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: My assumption about Firefox supporting XPath 2 appears to be wrong.  Some Googling suggests that Firefox does not indeed support 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the element, using following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'type-')][contains(@id, '-model')][@class='vehicle']"))
```

Comment: I would at least change the first `contains()` to `starts-with()`. It's just as readable, less likely to generate false positives, and probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

curiosu is right that XPath 1 doesn't support regexps, and moreover Selenium doesn't support XPath 2. :-(

As you pointed out, `ends-with()` doesn't exist in XPath 1.0. So we can adapt CiaPan's answer as follows:

```
By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'type-') and
   substring(@id, string-length(@id)-6) = '-model']"));
```

Comment: This does work to match my div id's, but I marked @German Petrov's as the answer since it will be a bit easier to read in the code and there are a lot of div's to match.  Thanks for your help, this was definitely a good learning experience with selenium and xpath!

Answer (score 0):

In case the id always start with a string ending with a hyphen followed by a number and ending with a string starting with a hyphen this could work:

```
//div[ contains (translate(@id, '1234567890',''),'--')]
```

so in your case

```
By.xpath("//div[ contains (translate(@id, '1234567890',''),'--')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you seriously want to use xpath and xpath to locate element? If not, and you just want to locate div, then you can use next selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.Css(".vehicle"));
//or
driver.findElement(By.Css("div[class='vehicle']"));
```

**UDPATE**
If you need to find div that matches pattern `type-...-model` you still can use css selector for that. But AFAIK css selectors doesn't support regexp, so you can use [starts/ends with attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings): Smth like this:

```
//find all divs which id starts with type
driver.findElement(By.Css("div[class^='type']"))
//find all divs which id ends with model
driver.findElement(By.Css("div[class$='model']"))
//find all divs which id starts with type and ends with model
driver.findElement(By.Css("div[class^='type'][class$='model']"))
```

Should work now.

Comment: He needs to find a div whose id matches `type-`...`-model`.